# Chatterbot dynamic training

Tags: python-3.x, bots, chatterbot

I'm using `chatter bot` for implementing chat bot. I want `Chatterbot` to training the data set dynamically.

Whenever I run my code it should train itself from the beginning, because I require new data for every person who'll chat with my bot.

So how can I achieve this in python3 and on windows platform ?

what I want to achieve and problem I'm facing:

I've a python program which will create a text file student_record.txt, this will be generate from a data base and almost new when different student signup or login. In the chatter bot, I trained the bot using with giving this file name but it still replay from the previous trained data

Comment: Please explain what approaches you have taken till now. Also please elaborate on the question.

Comment: see I've a python program which will create a text file student_record.txt, this will generate from a data base and almost new when different student signup. In the chatter bot, I trained the bot using with giving this file name but it still replay from the previous trained data .

Comment: Please add this information to your question

Comment: ok thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that, I just deleted the data base on the beginning of the program thus new data base will create during the execution of the program.
 I used the following command to delete the data base

import os
   os.remove("database_name")
in my case

import os 
   os.remove("db.sqlite3")

thank you